# How do I get the number of rows affected from an update query?

Tags: 8, database

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the number of affected rows from an update query in Drupal.

I have a form where users can update their profile details. Now, not every user is going to update everything from their profile. They may just update one field or two.

How do I account if there was a change or not and check for the affected rows?

This is the code I am running.

```php
$update_query = $db->update('TABLE NAME')
  ->fields([
    'uid' => $uid,
    'name_of_user' => $name,
    'url' => $url,
    'website' => $website,
    'industry' => $industry,
    'company_size' => $companySize,
    'company_type' => $companyType,
    'headquarters' => $headquarters,
    'founded' => $founded,
    'page_picture' => $upload_picture,
    'tagline' => $tagline,
    'updated_at' => $time,
  ])
  ->condition('uid', $uid);

  $affectedRows = $update_query->execute()->rowCount();
  return new AjaxResponse($affectedRows);
```

The code doesn't return anything. I even checked the network tab and there's nothing displayed in the response tab. I should be getting back either 0 or 1. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`$update_query->execute()->rowCount()` would cause a *Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object* (or *Call to a member function rowCount() on int*, on PHP 7.4) since [`$update_query->execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Update.php/function/Update%3A%3Aexecute/8.9.x) returns the number of rows  matched by the update query, including the ones that actually didn't have to be updated.
`rowCount()` can be called only when `execute()` returns an object implementing [`StatementInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementInterface.php/interface/StatementInterface/8.9.x), which is the case for [`Select::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3Aexecute/8.9.x), [`Truncate::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Truncate.php/function/Truncate%3A%3Aexecute/8.9.x), [`Upsert::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Upsert.php/function/Upsert%3A%3Aexecute/8.9.x), and [`Query::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Query.php/function/Query%3A%3Aexecute/8.9.x).

Unfortunately, the only way to get the number of rows changed from an update query is to fetch the rows matching the update condition (in your case, the rows for which *uid* is equal to `$uid`), and count which rows have, for the desired fields (in your case, *name_of_user*, *url*, *website*, *industry*, *company_size*, *company_type*, *headquarters*, *founded*, *page_picture*, *tagline*, and *updated_at*), a value different from the value set by the update query.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/update-queries
It says the opposite "The execute() method will return the number of rows affected by the query. Note that affected is not the same as matched."

Comment: The documentation page I linked says *The number of rows matched by the update query. This includes rows that actually didn't have to be updated because the values didn't change.* The content for the pages on api.drupal.org is taken from documentation comments in the Drupal core source, while the documentation pages on drupal.org can be edited from everybody. I would trust more the documentation on api.drupal.org.

Comment: you should file a bug against the api doc because it's incorrect.